# Does failing a cult device roll still disarm it?

Tags: for-the-king

A cult device will often show something like this for the rolls:

```
3: Success
2: +10 Damage
1: +10 Party Damage
...ect...
```

If I roll less than a 3, do I take damage **and** disarm the device? Or do I fail to disarm the device? In the latter case, can I attempt to disarm it again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just fail and take damage, but can attempt to disarm it again, yes.